# Report time filter based on two different fields

Tags: reporting, filters

I am attempting to build a report filter for a custom object which shows contracts in my company. I would like the filter to allow me to show only the contracts which were opened (Open Date) within 30 days BEFORE through 90 days AFTER a Projected Close Date field.

So broken down into logic it is :

Open Date Less Than (Projected Close Date - 30)

or

Open Date Greater Than (Projected Close Date + 91)

Is it possible to create that filter in reports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in that way. You will need to either create 2 formula fields in the object and use those fields in the report or your users will need to adjust the filters manually by selecting the correct dates.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a feeling I would need to do that. I wanted to make sure I wasn't thinking of something. I guess what I'll end up doing is to make the 2 fields, one called 30BeforePromoDate and another 90AfterPromoDate - and make them equal to either "Yes" or "No" - and just use the logic in the two field filters 30Before.. equals Yes or 90After... equals Yes......that's what you're suggesting, right ?

Comment: Yes, basically that's it :)